# how can I repair a mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I use XAMPP 1.7.3

If I try to open phpMyAdmin it will try to open but eventually I'll have only a blank page, no errors.

If I try to connect with Navicat, the same thing, it will not be able to establish a connection.

And usually this process takes between 30% and 60% of the processor for more than 20 min.

If I stop and then start again the mysql server from XAMPP Control Panel the message is 'Mysql server started'.

But If I go to http://localhost/xampp/ and then 'Status' everything is 'Activated' EXCEPT ' MySQL database', 'SMTP Service', 'FTP Service' which are 'Deactivated'.

I think I crashed the Mysql server after I tried to make a database backup BUT the laptop closed before the backup was finished (the battery was discharged).

How can I repair the connection to the Mysql server?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to double check the obvious, most likely these are not the issues since it happened after you closed your laptop, but it doesn't hurt to double check:

Make sure the MySQL service is running...

Also make sure that a firewall is not blocking port 3306...

This guide covers both MyISAM and InnoDB: http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-database-myisam-innodb-1634.html

Now, assuming that the tables are MyISAM, you can repair them by following this guide:
http://colekcolek.com/2011/11/02/repair-corrupted-mysql-myisam-table/

Here is a way to do it for InnoDB: http://code.google.com/p/innodb-tools/